# Chrome app close button

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

So, I am creating a Chrome app(Which I have never done before) and I am trying to make a close button with this html

```
  <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/index.css">
      <script src="assets/thirdParty/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
      <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="topBar">
          <a href="#"><img id="close" src="assets/img/close.png" height="35"></a>
        </div>        
    </body>
</html>
```

and this jQuery

```
$("#close").click(function(){
  window.close();
});
```

But for some reason it just won't work. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What error do you get? And have you referenced the jQuery js?

Comment: I am not getting any errors at all, just nothing is happening, and yes I am referencing the jQuery.

Comment: Have you looked in the console for errors?

Comment: I have looked in the console for errors. I have also used a quick console log to see if anything is happening when the button is press. Nothing happens.

Comment: Can you post more of your html and javascript?

Answer (score 1):

App-specific way would be

```
chrome.app.window.current().close();
```

See the [`chrome.app.window` docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window).

---

That said, your actual problem is the classic "code executes before DOM is ready". DOM is built up tag by tag, and JS is executed when its tag is added to the tree.

So, at the point when the `<script>` tag is added and executed, `#close` (which is below it in the tree) does not exist yet. So your code fails, and fails silently (since jQuery considers it okay to assign a click handler to an empty collection of nodes).

You need to wrap your code in a `$(document).ready()` which will defer execution until static DOM is fully built.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#close").click(function() {
    chrome.app.window.current().close();
  });
});
```